# Two elements are using the same exact styling, but are slightly different colors

Tags: html, css

I have what feels to be a unique problem here, I have two pipes ("|"s) that are styled exactly the same, use the exact same classes, and yet are two different colors. Here is the markup:

```
<span class="block">&copy; <?php echo date(Y); ?> Apple Hill Farm </span>

<span class="block">and Country Club</span>

<span class="spaces">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

<span class="block">
  <a href="http://www.inconcertweb.com/web" target="_blank">Website Design and Development</a>
</span> 

by <span class="block">
   <a href="http://www.blahblahblah.com" target="_blank">BlahBlah Web Solutions</a>
</span>

<span class="spaces">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

<span class="block">
   <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/site-map">Site Map</a>
</span>
```

The elements I'm talking about are the "spaces" class elements. Here is the styling:

```
.spaces {
   color: #625a49;
}
```

(I tried to directly style the text because it wasn't working before) And here is a snapshot of what's going on:

[image]

Sorry if it's tough to see with the background. The two pipes ares slightly different, as you can see. Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: Does this compile as expected using Sass directly?

Comment: Do you mean before I tried to use the mixin? Yes it compiled fine then. As soon as I wrote the mixin and then tried to use it, it gave me this error.

Comment: No, I mean does it produce the same error when you directly use the `sass` command (ie. not using Glup).

Comment: There's not enough information here to reproduce that problem, unless the problem is that you're not importing the file that contains your mixin.

Comment: Have&nbsp;you&nbsp;never&nbsp;heard&nbsp;of&nbsp;margin&nbsp;or&nbsp;padding?

Comment: I understand that the nbsp's aren't best practice, as this is a site that I started quite a while ago and am coming back to. But that doesn't answer my problem in the slightest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.spaces {
   background-color: #625a49;
   width: 1px;
   height: 14px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 0 1em;
}
```

It seems that the issue was just that the color was slightly different based on the size of the window/where the pipe ended up on the screen, because I noticed that as the screen resized, the pipes both kind of switched back and forth between the two colors. So I've replaced the pipes with this code, and it's worked out fine.